2 modal verbs in 1 sentence
I was wondering how it is possible to include two modal verbs in a sentence! I heard this sentence from a German colleague of mine; er wird heute nicht dabei sein können.
Can you please walk me through this grammar?

There is only one modal verb in the sentence: "können". It is used in future tense ("er wird können"), and is modal to the infinitive "sein".

Unlike English modal verbs, German modal verbs aren't defective. They have all forms and thus, they can also be stacked.

Er muss am Wochenende herkommen können.

He has to be able to come here at the weekend.
Do you notice how the English sentence neither feature must nor can? That's because those verbs are defective in English. You need to rephrase. While must instead of has to may still be acceptable —but odd— there's no way to use can in that example.
In German, you don't have to do any of those flic-flacs.

But your example isn't about two modal verbs. As werden isn't a modal verb but an auxiliary for Futur I tense in this example. (It may also be a full verb.) Let me compare Futur I and Präsens tense:

Er kann heute nicht dabei sein. (Präsens)
Er wird heute nicht dabei sein können. (Futur I)

